# VBA: Application-defined error when refering to range in different tab

Tags: excel, vba, vector, range

In this sub, I'm simply doing a few calculations. In a differnt sheet I've some temporary data stored and I'm trying and failing to define the following as a range (at the very bottom at the code):

```
MeanVector = Worksheets("TempSheet").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Stocks + 1, 2))
```

I get the following error: 1004 application-defined or object-defined error

The thing though is, this is a line of code that I copied in from a different module, so I know the method itself works.

I assume the problem is with the activation of the sheets, I'm tried to activate both at the beginning but with no luck. I do specify the worksheet in evry line of code, so I'm not sure why it would still be a problem?

I've tried to select the range as well:

```
Set MeanVector = Worksheets("TempSheet").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Stocks + 1, 2))
```

All code:

```
Sub CalculateOwnPortfolio()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.StatusBar = "Calculating..."

Dim MeanVector As Range
Dim WeightsVector As Range


Worksheets("TempSheet").Activate
Worksheets("Own Portfolio").Activate

'Count the amount of stock
Stocks = 0
For i = 1 To 20
    If Worksheets("MainSheet").Cells(i + 2, 2) <> 0 Then
        Stocks = Stocks + 1
    Else
        Stocks = Stocks
    End If
Next

'Amount of each stock
EmptyAmount = 0
For i = 1 To Stocks
    If Worksheets("Own Portfolio").Cells(1 + i, 7) = Value Then
        Else
            EmptyAmount = EmptyAmount + 1
    End If
Next
If EmptyAmount = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Error: Enter stock amounts")
    Exit Sub
End If

'Calcualte amount of observations
Observations = 0
For j = 2 To 15000
    If Worksheets("Own Portfolio").Cells(j, 1) <> 0 Then
        Observations = Observations + 1
    Else
        Observations = Observations
    End If
Next

Worksheets("Own Portfolio").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Observations, 2)) _
    .ClearContents
Worksheets("Own Portfolio").Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(3 + Stocks, 5)) _
    .ClearContents


'Total Value
For i = 2 To Observations + 1
    Value = 0
    For j = 1 To Stocks
        Symbol = Worksheets("Own Portfolio").Cells(1 + j, 4)
        Amount = Worksheets("Own Portfolio").Cells(1 + j, 7)
        AdjClose = Worksheets(Symbol).Cells(i, 7)
        Value = Value + (Amount * AdjClose)
        Worksheets("Own Portfolio").Cells(i, 2) = Value
    Next
Next

'Weights
TotalValue = 0
For j = 1 To Stocks
    Symbol = Worksheets("Own Portfolio").Cells(1 + j, 4)
    Amount = Worksheets("Own Portfolio").Cells(1 + j, 7)
    AdjClose = Worksheets(Symbol).Cells(2, 7)
    TotalValue = TotalValue + (Amount * AdjClose)
Next

For j = 1 To Stocks
    StockValue = 0
    Symbol = Worksheets("Own Portfolio").Cells(1 + j, 4)
    Amount = Worksheets("Own Portfolio").Cells(1 + j, 7)
    AdjClose = Worksheets(Symbol).Cells(2, 7)
    StockValue = Amount * AdjClose
    Worksheets("Own Portfolio").Cells(1 + j, 5) = StockValue / TotalValue
Next


'Mean,Variance,Std Dev and Sharp Ratio
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
'----------------This is where I get the error message--------------------
MeanVector = Worksheets("TempSheet").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Stocks + 1, 2))
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------

WeightsVector = Worksheets("Own Portfolio").Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(Stocks + 1, 2))
Mean = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(MeanVector, WeightsVector)

Call OwnPortfolioGraph(Symbol)


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

Picture of "TempSheet"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
MeanVector = Worksheets("TempSheet").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Stocks + 1, 2))
```

to this:

```
set MeanVector = Worksheets("TempSheet").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Stocks + 1, 2))
```

and see if it works

then do the same for

```
WeightsVector = Worksheets("Own Portfolio").Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(Stocks + 1, 2))
```

Edit:
I'm pretty sure that in your formula
Worksheets("TempSheet").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Stocks + 1, 2))

Unless the current worksheet is tempsheet then Cells(2, 2) will not be the value your expecting, neither will Cells(Stocks + 1, 2).
you could try:

```
With Worksheets("TempSheet")
    WeightsVector = .Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(Stocks + 1, 2))
end with
```

although looking at the screenshot you have added it doesnt appear cells(2,5) is from tempsheet

Comment: No, still the same problem. The WeightsVector does work though, even without "Set". That's why I would assume the problem lies with the worksheet itself and selecting it.

Comment: What's in the current sheet Cells(2, 2) and Cells(Stocks + 1, 2)

Comment: I edited my original post and added a picture of TempSheet. Stocks = 3 in this case.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the last part, the Weights of the different stocks are in a different spreadsheet. I already created the means (in the temp sheet) in a different module so I'm simply trying to use that instead of creating it again.

It still dont work though, I tried read the answer to the "doublicate" problem, but without luck.

Comment: Different workbook or different sheet within the same workbook?

Comment: The two sheets are in the same workbook